# ruby sequel in sinatra framework add postgres schema search path

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sinatra, sequel

I have a sinatra service that reads from postgres and we changed the postgres schema of those models. How can I set the schema path.

In rails and active record you can do as follows:

```
performance_tracking:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: db_name
  username: my_user
  password: pass11121212
  host: 172.30.1.12
  schema_search_path: my_new_schema
```

So I am trying to do the same using [sequel](https://devhints.io/sequel)

But it ignores the field of **schema_search_path**

How can I set the schema_search_path for postgres

Comment: Try `search_path` option.

Comment: You also can start to dig from this search: https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/search?q=%22search_path%22&unscoped_q=%22search_path%22

Comment: Thanks @Pavel Mikhailyuk it works